# How to set ringtone using database from device?

Tags: android

I wanted to set a ringtone using the database from my device. My application is able to fetch the ringtone from device and storing it in the database. Now all i want to do is whatever ringtone i select through spinner it set as my default ringtone.

Here is my code

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    DBAdapter db ;
    int vol = 7;
    String code="";
        @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    contextx=context;
         Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         db = new DBAdapter(context);
         db.open();

         Cursor c = db.getAllTitles();
         int row_size = c.getCount();
         System.out.println("row size++++++++"+row_size);
         if(row_size>0)
         {
             c.moveToFirst();
             code = c.getString(1);
             String status = c.getString(2);
             String ring = c.getString(3);
             vol = c.getInt(4);
             String mode = c.getString(5);

             System.out.println("code++++++++"+code);
             System.out.println("status++++++++"+status);
             System.out.println("ring++++++++"+ring);
             System.out.println("vol++++++++"+vol);
             System.out.println("mode++++++++"+mode);

                   File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_RINGTONES);
         File Ringtonefile = new File(path,ring);
         setMyRingtone(Ringtonefile) ;
         }

         Object messages[] = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            SmsMessage smsMessage[] = new SmsMessage[messages.length];
            for (int n = 0; n < messages.length; n++) {
                smsMessage[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
            }

            if(smsMessage[0].getMessageBody().equals(""+code))
            {
                AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

                  audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
              audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, vol, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI + AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);

            }  
            }

   public void setMyRingtone(File file)  
 {  
   ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
     values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());  
     values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, file.getName());
     values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
     values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);  
     values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);  
     values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);  
     values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);  

     Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(file.getAbsolutePath());  
     Uri newUri = contextx.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);  
     RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(contextx, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);} }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to set Default Ringtone using [RingtoneManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html):

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
Context contextx;
    DBAdapter db ;
    int vol = 7;
    String code="";
        @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
      this.contextx=context;
      //your code....


    File Ringtonefile = new File(path, "Ringtone.mp3");
    setMyRingtone(Ringtonefile) ;
    public void setMyRingtone(File file)  
         {  
           ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
           values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());  
             values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, file.getName());  
    //       values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, file.length());  
           values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");  
    //       values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Madonna");  
    //       values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION, 230);  
           values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);  
           values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);  
           values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);  
           values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);  

           Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(file.getAbsolutePath());  
           Uri newUri = contextx.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);  
           RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(contextx, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);  
         }
```

manifast.xml Permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

Comment: Can i do it without using Uri @imran ??

Comment: @JasmeetKaurChauhan : setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(Context context, int type, Uri ringtoneUri)  takes second param as Uri so i think it's not possible with out Uri.

Comment: @JasmeetKaurChauhan :  how u are currently storing ringtone in database?

Comment: getContentResolver().insert(uri, values) for inserting Ringtone Uri in MediaStore.Audio.Media db

Comment: where you are using this code in SMSReceiver BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: Thanks a lot imran for helping, but i couldn't find my way :(

Comment: I have edited the whole code. You can check it out.
The problem is,  the ringtone is saving in the device from database, but its creating a duplicate entry of selected ringtone and playing the default ringtone which was selected earlier not the one i select while using my application.

Comment: @JasmeetKaurChauhan : very very sorry friend !!! :).i'm here only for help people. i have also told u send me a dummy copy of code then i will try to solve your issue.anyway i'm always here for help my friends.Thanks

Comment: just upload on any sharing site like www.4shared.com/ and send me download  link i will download it.

Comment: Thanks Jasmeet. i will revert u back as soon as possible.

Comment: Have you find any solution imran ?
please revert i am waiting.

Comment: hi imran thanks for helping..i get all the code, guess it will run but there is a small problem, 
Here is a line  newUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri, Long.valueOf(ringtoneuriid)); 
Its throwing a NumberFormatException error. I am trying to parse it tell me some way if you have.

Comment: can u send me a test mail on my email id then we will discuss it.code is working n my side.testing on emulator or real device?